# Given a variable, can I see a string of the code used to define that variable?

Tags: python, parsing, compilation

I have a general curiosity spawned by a specific coding task I had, and I think the best way to pose my question is to explain briefly my task. I am creating a toolkit where users define a set of equations in python and then my code will generate some results of interest. Part of my toolkit will require that their equations are written in a specific order. Here is what an input into my tools may look like:

```
def psi(x):

    v, r = x.ravel()

    EQ1 = v-r
    EQ2 = r+1

    return np.array([[EQ1], [EQ2]])
```

My code would then take this `psi` function, take the derivatives, and do some math. I need to ensure that `EQ1` and `EQ2` are defined in the correct order in a general case. I know of some ways to ensure this, but my process to figure it out led me to my question:

***Can I write something that would look for the line where EQ1 is defined and write that line to a string?***

I know that if the user is defining their `psi` function in a separate file I can certainly parse that file. I know that no parsing is necessary to figure out if the equations are ordered correctly. I simply wondered if for python you can somehow access the script from the compiled version, so if I had just their `psi` function as an object in Python I can see the script that was compiled to make that object. I'm sure this question is a little confusing as I'm not sure the best way to word it, but I'm happy to clarify any confusion as best I can.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using sympy, it's for doing symbolic math.

Comment: The answer to your question is no, a variable just contains the value that results from the expression, the expression is not remembered.

Comment: @Barmar I am using autograd as its automatic differentiation is preferred. I'm afraid that the context of my question may distract from the question itself, as I know how to solve the problem in this case. It's just a curiosity about Python.

Comment: The answer is still no, variables don't keep any history of how they were set.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! I thought as much, just wanted to verify

Comment: You might want to play around with the dis module, i.e. ```import dis``` and ```dis.dis(psi)``` will show you the bytecode stage (not the source code though) but you can also see the source->bytecode as in ```dis.dis('np.array([[EQ1], [EQ2]])'```, and find the output of the one in the other?

Comment: @Barmar If you post an answer I'm happy to accept it

Comment: I tried posting an answer that said "No", but it wouldn't let me post it.